# Comando equivalente a `hostname` en Windows

Tags: linux, windows

¿Existe en Windows un comando equivalente al `hostname -I` de Linux? Sólo necesito que me devuelva la misma información.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Una equivalencia perfecta, no creo, ¿pero tal vez `ipconfig /all` te sirva?

Comment: Te cuento: el **hostname -I** se ejecuta desde un programa en FreePascal/Lazarus en Linux y quería saber si hay algún comando que me devuelva la misma o similar información desde Windows. La ídea es compilarlo para las dos plataformas.

Comment: Más fácil. ¿Qué información necesitas?

Answer (score 1):

En Windows es el mismo comando:

```
hostname
```

(sin parametros para obtener el nombre de tu equipo)

```
ipconfig /all
```

(para obtener todas las ips y rutas asociadas a tu equipo)

Comment: Estaba editando la respuesta.... ;-D (he tenido que buscar un pc con windows para comprobar que lo que escribia era correcta -solo uso linux-)

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que buscas es obtener solo la `IP` de la computadora, puedes hacer esto:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %i  in ('ipconfig ^| findstr /i "IPv4 Address." ^| findstr [1-9]') do echo %i
```